# How to get hold of a sprite in cocos2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

in cocos2d I need to drag a sprite in my project using finger. how do i get hold of that sprite? any help will be appreciated. thanx. i am using chipmunk engine.

Comment: could you share some more details, code, experiments you did already?

Answer (score 2):

You need to capture the touch began, work out what sprite is being touched and then track the  movement of the touch. In touches moved you update the position of the sprite.

Sound complicated? It's not really. Here is a great tutorial for it.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/2343/how-to-drag-and-drop-sprites-with-cocos2d

Comment: thanx for your answer. It works. One more question Can you move the physics body attached to that sprite? If yes How?